# Need help editing values in Hashmap to be loaded in a listview

Tags: android

I was able get the value of "quantity" in my list when I use on click using this code:

> public void onItemClick(AdapterView
>   parent, View view, int position, long
>   id)
>   {
>
> > ```
> >          Object o = list.get(position);
> >             HashMap<?, ?> fullObject = (HashMap<?, ?>)o;
> >             String a = (String) fullObject.get("quantity");
> > ```
> >
> > }

now I want to change the value of "quantity" then update it in my list. any help? thanks a lot

Comment: what is the type of the `list' variable ?

Comment: list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: you have a lot of unnecessary casting going on.. yuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I want to change the value of "quantity"

```
fullObject.put("quantity", whatever);
```

> then update it in my list

Call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter, which should reflect your data change in the UI.

Comment: change HashMap<?, ?> fullObject = (HashMap<?, ?>)o;
to HashMap<String, String> fullObject = (HashMap<String, String>)o;